# android horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am using Horizontal Scrollview in android to show images in my app,

i need to make it scroll exact to the initial of the next or previous image on the user's left or right gesture, how it can be solved, it has a linear layout (orientation horizontal) and images are loaded in that,

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a Gallery for this?

Comment: @check http://jmsliu.com/247/android-gallery-example-widget-gallery.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no property / method / attribute of scroll view which let you do what you want trivially.
but the good news is that the solution is simple - don't use scroll view,
but views that design for such purpose:

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

[ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html)

[ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) and [example](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/view-flipper-example-android.html) here

[Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

these three view design for showing and navigating between views with horizontal gestures.
they got attributes / properties / method to control number of view on screen.

Comment: thanks, did it with gallery , worked the way i wanted, many thanks

Comment: Do not use gallery now... Use HorizontalScrollView or ViewFlipper instead

Answer (score 1):

Gallery view is best to solve this

Comment: can u direct me to some tutorial link